# How to define Gradle project properties with Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'd like to check if two project properties are set and if not, set them to empty values in order to avoid a build failure. These properties are supposed come from `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` (if configured).

The goal is to have credentials to a Maven repository in S3 defined in that local file. Every user has to put his own data there, but I want the build to just output a warning and continue if these are not set. Chances are high it will still be successful even without contacting S3.

I have got it running with Groovy DSL, but I am now switching to Kotlin and I just can't get the syntax right.

This is how `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` looks like:

```
s3AccessKeyId=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
s3SecretKey=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcd
```

And here are the relevant sections of the `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
if (!project.hasProperty("s3AccessKeyId") || !project.hasProperty("s3SecretKey")) {
    logger.lifecycle("WARNING: s3AccessKeyId and s3SecretKey not set!")
    project.extra["s3AccessKeyId"] = ""
    project.extra["s3SecretKey"] = ""
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri("s3://maven-repo.mycompany.com.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/")
        credentials(AwsCredentials::class) {
            accessKey = project.extra["s3AccessKeyId"].toString()
            secretKey = project.extra["s3SecretKey"].toString()
        }
    }
}
```

No matter how I write the *s3AccessKeyId=""* lines, I am always getting the error:

> Cannot get property 's3AccessKeyId' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

If all artifacts are found in the local Maven repository, I expect the build to work, even without `gradle.properties`. Only if some artifact is missing, the build should abort with some "credentials wrong" error.

As I said, it already worked with Groovy.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce with similar code in modern versions of Gradle and the `kotlin-dsl`. Therefore, I am voting to close.

Answer (score 9):

For that you need to use the *properties* attibute which is different from the *extra* like:

```kotlin
project.properties["s3SecretKey"].toString()
```

And then you need to have in your `gradle.properties`:

```
s3AccessKeyId=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
```

If the value is not there it might return `null` so you can do:

```kotlin
(project.properties["s3SecretKey"] ?: "default value").toString()
```

And it should work